# Multiprocessing threads in web-scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, screen-scraping, python-multiprocessing

In my previous version of code, I used for loops to perform web scraping, and added chunks of data into a dictionary. Now, I am looking to use `multiprocessing` and `Pool` to speed up my scraping process.

To do this, I have something like this:

```
# First, create a list of pages to go over
for currentPage in range(firstPage, lastPage + 1):
    bookList.append("{}{}".format(PAGE_FORMAT, currentPage))

# Multiprocessing for each index page
pagePool = Pool(lastPage - firstPage + 1)
pagePool.map(scrapePage(bookList, book), (bookList, book))
pagePool.terminate()
pagePool.join()
```

In this chunk of code, `bookList` is simply an array of pages to iterate, `book` is a dictionary where the data will eventually be stored, and `scrapePage` is a function that takes the webpage and dictionary and processes it.

I'm not sure how to write my `map` arguments, because my function takes in multiple parameters. I have tried writing the function alone as the first argument, and then putting in the other arguments as `map` arguments, but that doesn't work either.

Edit: I checked a couple of questions that deals with these kind of situations, but I'm just not sure how to apply it (`celery` for example). What I want to achieve in my program is scrape data in parallel (Scrape several table of contents pages simultaneously, and then in each call to scrape one page, scrape several entries within the table of contents simultaneously).

Although the website in question has serialized the content (in my original code, I would scrape table of contents page i, and then on page i scrape entry 1-100... and then go to page ii and repeat), because I am using a dictionary, I don't really care if the contents are serialized. Would it be better to use `multiprocessing` or `celery`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to call `pagePool.map` in this way:

```
pagePool.map(scrapePage, (bookList, book,))
```

Comment: I'm missing a positional argument with this call, so that doesn't work. My `scrapePage` takes in two arguments.

Comment: I understood. Let me a minute. I will try to help